# Bernstein type inequalities. Is there a standard list?

Tags: probability, reference-request, probability-distributions

Suppose I have a sequence of iid random variables $X_i\geq 0$ with mean $\mu$ and $\mathbb E \left(e^{tX_i}\right) = G(t)$. Set $$S_n = \sum_{i=1} X_n.$$

For the purpose of this question the Bernstein type inequality for $X_t$ is the following tail bound

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\mathbb P\left(S_n > (1+\varepsilon)\mu n\right) &=& \mathbb P\left(e^{\lambda S_n} > e^{\lambda(1+\varepsilon)\mu n}\right) \\
&\leq&e^{-\lambda(1+\varepsilon)\mu n}\mathbb E\left(e^{\lambda S_n}\right) \\
&=& \left( e^{-\lambda(1+\varepsilon)\mu} G(\lambda) \right)^n.
\end{array}$$

Where $\lambda$ is chosen so that $e^{-\lambda(1+\varepsilon)\mu} G(\lambda)<1$.

They're not hard to work out, but if $X_i$ is from a standard family (exponential, Poisson etc) presumably somebody else has done it first.

Is there a nice list of bounds of this kind, or a standard reference (so I can just write down the bound and get on with the proof of whatever it is I'm doing).